# CFString(immutable) keep increasing

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

I developed an ipad app, that app is crashing with memory warning, i did profiling and find out CFString (immutable) is keep increasing even if i am not touching anything. can anybody tell me why its happening like this.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Obviously you have code that's leaking strings. Run Instruments on your application, it can help you to narrow down what's going on.

Comment: i did that thing only, and i just runed my app nothing else i am doing and its started increasing cfstring, i am using iCloud is it related to that?

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not your are leaking objects in your code. If using ARC, well, its a bug somewhere - some string is not getting released.

Comment: Hey i found the problem its iCloud syncing, in background its may be syncing at that time its taking too much memory and lied my app to crash, and i am not using ARC.